# Apache HTTP Client - Don't want to use hosts file or DNS

Tags: java, apache, ssl, https, hosts

We are writing an application that sends HTTPS POST messages via the Apache HTTP Client v4.5.2

We've had it sending HTTP messages between endpoints for a while but now want to upgrade it to HTTPS.

There will ultimately be numerous endpoints, each with a unique hostname/ID - Or in other words a unique common name in their certificate.

In an ideal world we could just ensure that the hosts files or DNS matches the common name in each cert to avoid `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`

We don't have access to the hosts or DNS on these systems - not without going through a long RFC process (and costs etc...)

Our design moves all hosts and IP Addresses into a table in the application's DB.

The issue we have is that unlike HTTP, we are unable to just select the relevant host & IP from the database and connect using the IP Address.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <127.0.0.1> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
```

Please could anyone tell me if there is a way to

1. Retrieve the host and IP from the database
2. Pass them both to the Apache HTTP Client
3. Show the hostname instead of the IP Address to the remote side.

Mimicking what happens when hosts/DNS is used.

In its current form it does work correctly with HTTPS but only when a hosts file update is made.

Code:

```
public static int post( String pid, String url, String paramKey, String paramVal ) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
        int responseCode = 0;

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create( ).build( );

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost( url );

        post.setHeader( "User-Agent", USER_AGENT );

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>( );

        urlParameters.add( new BasicNameValuePair( paramKey, paramVal ) );

        post.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( urlParameters, "UTF-8" ) );        

        HttpResponse response = client.execute( post );

        log.info( pid + " POST Response code : " + response );

        responseCode = response.getStatusLine( ).getStatusCode( );

        client.close( );
        client = null;

        return responseCode;
    }
```

Comment: You can try to implement and set a matching host name verifier.

Comment: I've seen bits on the web about that. Would that allow me to match/verify the cert common name against the hostname - even though I might be using the IP to connect with?

Comment: @thonnor: yes, this would be possible. But you get another problem is the server requires SNI, i.e. the real hostname sent in the TLS handshake. I don't know if you can hook somewhere into Apache HTTP Client to tune the TLS handshake accordingly.